# Mobile Teleprompter Apps Automatic Scroll Problem

Tags: applications, samsung

I have an Samsung Galaxy S20

I have been using a few different mobile teleprompter apps

I have a few word documents that I am either copying and pasting or importing into the app.

Whenever I try to modify the document by typing, adding, or subtracting things it keeps scrolling all the way to the bottom of the text.

Does anyone know why this keeps happening? Is there a way to turn off this automatic scrolling?

It only seems to happen in any teleprompter app that I try to use but I have not seen this happen in other apps such as docs or any other program for that matter.

I have tried deleting the cache portion from my galaxy and have tried updating the phone. The phone is already up to date.

I have also updated the apps I have been using.